# how to add data into datatable(Gridview) dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I want to how to add data into datatable and change dataformatString of "Date" column
[image]

Q1. how to change data format to "dd/MM/yyyy" or **use your method to show**,
Q2. I've add codes for add datakeys:["RowID"] in page_load event, but when i click "Edit"    button, it prompts "object reference not set to an instance of an object", how can get datakey value/ add commandArguement to "edit"/"delete" Button   
 
Q3. when i click "Edit" button, how to change into edit mode with update, cancel button etc for editing,

I hope someone can help me, thank you very much!!!

**remark:"Edit & Delete Button are added in .aspx, not dynamically "**

**.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (!IsPostBack) {
        GridView gv = (GridView)Page.FindControl("GridView1");
        gv.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "RowID" };
    }
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  getDT(date);  //string []date;
}

private DataTable getDT(string[] date){
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++) {
        dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i]); //date[i] format:yyyy-mm-dd or dd/MM/yyyy
    } 
    return dt;
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete"){
       hf_id.Value = GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: A1. You can set your `DataFormatString` property to `dd/MM/yyyy` of your gridview. Or you can format your date values on code behind using `DateTime.ToString(string)` method as well.

Comment: i've changed to date format to dd/MM/yyyy to date[i] ,it doesnot work

Comment: try this out : dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

Comment: if i replaced by dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); ,error Msg shows "`'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments 
`" and i use both date format in code ,still get same response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download source code from given link and study it will help you. Your requirements are easy but basic knowledge is necessary for doing it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET

Comment: i think it works , but i don't use tableAdatper because the data are not inserted into database & and dataformatstring do not solved it still appear (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss)

Comment: Use ToShortDateString() method it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

this is correct..but i want to be this without using data base..i did everything..now i want
if i click the cell so data is updating in a gv but it is not showing datatable..so i want to take a refresh button..
if i click on this so data should be update on a data table..
i am sending the code like this...

design page

#### GridView

code---

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (!this.IsPostBack) {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("City") });

            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Anamika", "Bangalore");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Sunny", "Chennai");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Monika", "Bangalore");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Jyoti", "Chennai");
            dt.Rows.Add(5, "Radhika", "Jabalpur");
            dt.Rows.Add(6, "Imran", "Jammu");
            dt.Rows.Add(7, "Alok", "Delhi");
            dt.Rows.Add(8, "Amit", "Shamshabad");
            dt.Rows.Add(9, "Neetu", "Bhopal");
            dt.Rows.Add(10, "Jyoti", "Chennai");
            dt.Rows.Add(11, "Radhika", "Vidisha");
            dt.Rows.Add(10, "Pooja", "Pune");

            gridview1.DataSource = dt;
            gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    } 

    protected void gridview1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++) {                 
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;                 
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "";
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. does your code do what you want? And more importantly: does it solve the OP's problem?